# Dynamic font-size according to device

Tags: css

Small question, for which I can't find any answer. 
Is there a way to do this?

I have 3 elements with different sizes. 
One with 30px, other with 22px and other with 16px. 
Now, when using a tablet to check this elements, they go off limits since I need to have my container with fixed height.
Is there a way, using media-queries, to decrease their font-size according to device without doing one by one? Like it's 100% in desktop, 80 in tablet, etc..

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use viewport widths and heights in CSS:

```css
.vwHeight {font-size: 5.9vw;}
```

A **preview** of the same would be:

[image]
<sub>(source: [css-tricks.com](https://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/vw.gif))</sub>

More info on [Viewport Sized Typography](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/).

Comment: I saw that. The problem is that I need to work with fixed font-sizes, even though I'm sure that these would help me a lot in many things.

Comment: Actually you are contradicting your own statement. You wanna make the font sizes variable according to the screen size, but at the same time, you wanna keep them fixed? `:/`

Comment: Fixed like. Desktop : 16px. Tablet : 12px.
Like that.

Comment: @DinisFigueira Boss! Then it is easy, why not use `@media` queries?

Comment: But that way, I have to define one by one. Which won't help me a lot, when I have a lot of elements which need that.

Comment: If you have a specific requirement of `font-size`s, then it is easy for you to go for `@media` queries rather. So you say you wanna go for `12px` for screen size less than `768px` and blah blah..

Comment: Have a base size and why not specify `em`s for it like having one size for the `body` or `html` and specify using `rem`?

Comment: But just to clarify things. The only way to have variable sizes is with vw, vh etc?
If I want to have "fixed" font-sizes like 18px - > 12px , the only way Is using media-queries, defining 1 by 1 right?

Comment: That's fixed. The other is variable. Not one by one, but using a range!

Comment: When I mean't one by one, Is, with 3 different elements with different sizes, I have to define the "new font-size" for each element.

Comment: What exactly would you like to achieve?

Comment: All elements on #thisContainer, when on tablet, reduce the same amount of pixels. 
30 -> 26,
22 -> 18,
16 - > 12,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vw` , `vmax` , `vmin` or `em` here is many CSS Units which can helps you.

for example:-

```
.block {font-size: 5vw;}
```

or

```
.block {font-size: 5vmax;}
```

you should go with below link and I am sure it will helps you.

**[URL](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/7-css-units-you-might-not-know-about--cms-22573)**

Comment: I can see that you have specified about `vmax` and other available variable widths. How is this different or better than my answer? `#Curious` `;)`